# The post-install step did not complete successfully Python@3 Mac OS Ventura

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew

M1 Mac OS Ventura13.0

Homebrew version 4.0.6

```
==> //opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2_1/bin/python3.11 -m ensurepip
==> //opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2_1/bin/python3.11 -m pip install -v --no-deps --no-index --upgrade --isolated --target=//opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-
Last 15 lines from /Users/zhangfan/Library/Logs/Homebrew/python@3.11/post_install.02.python3.11:
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 411, in get_requirements
    req_to_add = install_req_from_line(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 395, in install_req_from_line
    return InstallRequirement(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.local_file_path = self.link.file_path
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/models/link.py", line 330, in file_path
    return url_to_path(self.url)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/urls.py", line 43, in url_to_path
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: non-local file URIs are not supported on this platform: 'file://opt/homebrew/Cellar/python%403.11/3.11.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ensurepip/_bundled/setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl'
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using:
  brew postinstall python@3.11
```

Install Python with brew.

```
brew install python@3
```

try brew postinstall python@3.11

The above problems still arise